Discard Virtual Memory for Local
i tried to open my Local app i windows 8 32 bits and it is complaining about Discard Virtual Memory missing
I tried to open the local app on my windows 8 32 bits system
I expected it to load then open,
But it is complaining Discard Virtual Memory is missing

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/discardvirtualmemory-entry-point-missing-from/fdaa2a77-1b32-40c9-8f33-d640056e62bf

Not enough details to answer the question.
